# Open local directory from ASP.NET MVC 3 Intranet application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory, intranet

I would like to know if it is possible to open a directory from intranet MVC application ? I have been searching about it but i don't found anything.

I tried to open from javascript using `window.open('url')` but i get unauthorized access.

Thanks,
Tiago Mourão

Comment: Accessing local resources from a web application is not a good idea. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Most browsers prevent you from doing this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe if you elaborate a bit you get more useful answers than 'no' and 'impossible'.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPOSSIBLE !!!**

web browsers does not have allow web pages to access to disk drives.

web pages only can read/write cookies.

FileUpload control allow access to the files, only with user action(scripts no allowed).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do resolve this problem. If you create a background process using Process.Start('location'), the application opens directory folder.

Comment: Do you know the concept of server-side code, and client-side code?
For security reasons, a web page ins't allowed to trigger client-side process, or access local files.
There are some ways of doing so, but aren't cross-browser (if done in .NET), or JAVA, that isn't .NET and you need always to give securty access for an Applet to reach your client-side file system.
But, as everyone has already told, it's not a good ideia to do that.  I think you have the wrong approach to your problem. Why do you need to access the client local file system?

Answer (score 1):

**Tips:**

- Process.Start() generally used in windows application and if used in
  web applications, a process will start on server(not on user agent
  that run current page).
- you get unauthorized access error, because of IUser has limited
  access ...

---

1) **Web Applications can read/write any file and folders on server side with assigning permission.**

2) **WebApplication with Some sideway can access to file & folders in web pages (client side) !!!**

- **with JavaScripts:**

  - Write a browser add-on with requested functionality, then install on
    user agent(browser).
  - now with call method/function in add-on, you can do the operations
    that does not allowed with JavaScript & etc.
- **with VBScript**(Obsoleted) that run/supported only in MsIE:

  - can using FileSystemObject to full access files and folders.
  - can using CreateObject to create instance of each object in OS and
    working with it.
- Finally my answer is **IMPOSSIBLE**.